# Programming a grid table php

Tags: php, datagrid

I have a grid table (example attached).  The user will input the width (column) and then the height (row) into a form.  The program then has to output the price based on the inputted data, so if you look at the example, if the width is 800 and the height is 1000 the price will be 337.  Any ideas how to approach this?  I've never done something like this before.

I know this is a broad question .. but any direction or tutorial will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Seems quite easy, but show us your current datagrid HTML structure so we can propose a solution directly related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like:

```
// price matrix: first index is y-axis, second is x-axis
$prices = [
    600 => [
        600 => 224,
        700 => 246,
        800 => 266,
        900 => 291,
        1000 => 313
    ],
    // here you put the rest...
];

//then echo the table;
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<td></td>"; // first empty cell;
foreach ($prices[array_keys($prices)[0]] as $y_axis => $xprices){
    echo "<td>".$y_axis."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";//finish setting up the header
foreach ($prices as $y_axis => $xprices) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$y_axis."</td>";
    foreach($xprices as $y_axis=> $price){
        echo "<td>".$price."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This is more for orientation, hopefully will get you in the right direction.

This generates a table with a header and your first row:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>600</td>
        <td>700</td>
        <td>800</td>
        <td>900</td>
        <td>1000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>600</td>
       <td>224</td><td>246</td><td>266</td>
       <td>291</td><td>313</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Online php scrit: https://3v4l.org/BY45N (get html fro here)
Html code evaluator: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro (and put it here)

Comment: Thank you I will give feedback :)